# Override phone app launched from mobile Safari tel: link on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari, url-scheme, tel

Is it possible to have an iOS native app register for the `tel:` url scheme so that mobile Safari will launch it in response to HTML `tel:` links rather than the built-in Phone application?  I.e. to override the built-in Phone app ?

Answer (score 0):

No, at least not surely. I remember Apple docs saying that if two app registers the same URL scheme, then the behavior is unspecified when using that URL scheme. You can do this, however, with a MobileSubstrate plugin (if jailbreaking is an option), which hooks into SpringBoard and opens a different application when that particular URL scheme is encountered.

Comment: thanks--no jailbreaking is not an option, needs to work on stock phone